# Data Factory Copy Upsert doesn' work for Synapse with varchar(max)

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I think it is quite common situation like I have in my pipeline. I load data to stage table in Synapse, it is small dimension table with heap index settings and I wanted to use option in Data Factory upsert to prod table with clustered index (key) but I failed because of my table has column with varchar(max). The reason, that using upsert option in copy activity, Synapse automatically creates some temporarly table with default setting, like columnstore index, which doesnt support varchar(max) and nvarchar(max). And there is no option to configure settings for this temp table.
How to handle this? I would like to follow best practise of table design in Synapse, stage-heap, prod dimension table - clustered index (key)
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

As per [CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) documentation:

```
Columns that use any of the following data types cannot be included in a columnstore index:

nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) (Applies to SQL Server 2016 and prior versions, and nonclustered columnstore indexes)
```

Create a temporary staging table in your Synapse Analytics database with a schema that matches your production table.
You can use the same structure as the production table, excluding the `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` columns.
This table should also have a clustered index if possible.

Also You can change the type from nvarchar(max) to limit it, for example set the length to 4000.

Comment: I have column with varchar more than 8000, that is why I would like to use varchar(max). As I understand with that requirement I cant use upsert and staging table. like you said for workaround